# Set up sbt for use with HBase

Tags: scala, sbt, hbase

I'm trying to work with HBase from Spark/Scala using sbt and followed the [instructions](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Scala) where I replaced the version with 1.2.1. However, it seems my machine cannot resolve the dependencies.

Below is my .sbt/repositories file:

```
[repositories]
  local
  sbt-releases-repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
  concurrent-maven: http://conjars.org/repo/
```

I'm using IntelliJ and it tells me that HBase is still an unresolved dependency and I don't see hbase when I type `org.apache.hadoop.`, which should appear in the list.

Am I missing a repo or resolver?

Comment: the hbase is in the package of 'org.apache.hbase' not in 'org.apache.hadoop'

Comment: Oops, I lazily copy-pasted. But I still have unresolved dependencies. IntelliJ does not see `org.apache.hbase`. I've cleared the caches a few times, but nothing. Phoenix seems to work.

Comment: maybe you can publish the hbase to your local repository, i have met the problem before. you can refer to the link https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: That link helps if I already have the jar, which I don't.

Comment: Moreover, unless the API doc is wrong, I think it's in `org.apache.hadoop.hbase`: https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: if you can use one of the CHD or HDP versions, which in my case works out fine because we use HDP, then you just have to add the repos as [here](https://bitbucket.org/hell316/dbline/raw/b838114b9d4e09d5c5b68bba3525a1f32c7fb554/bash/sbt-repositories).

Then in `build.sbt` you use the version from your Hadoop distro. If you happen to use a vanilla HBase, then you probably have to publish to your local repo. I haven't opted for that though.

And yes, I was right: the libraries reside in `org.apache.hadoop.hbase`.